# Driving multiple Pi GPIO using Arduino GPIO

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am trying to send TTL pulse from single Arduino digital pin to 8 different Raspberry Pi simultaneously. For this I have connected 8 raspberry pi in parallel to arduino digital pin.

Since, Arduino runs at 5V and raspberry Pi at 3.3V, I am using a switching diode (1N4148) connected to 3.3V pin on pi as shown in the figure for droppping voltage levels.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Now here is my question, when I check for output voltage at Arduino it shows 0.2V rather than 5V which means that arduino pin is not able to drive all the pi as they are drawing a lot of current. Also another thing, when I start removing one pi at a time from circuit, the arduino starts working perfectly for 4 pi. As far I can think of this is mostly an issue related to not enough current to drive all pi.

How can I make this ciruit work?? I read up online that a voltage buffer say something like LM110, LM741 can be used to solve this issue. Is this the right direction to work on? Can something else be done?

Comment: An alternative would be to convert the 5V to 3.3V once instead of 8 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diode circuit should work but not safe to parallel multiple loads to single drive. The voltage across the pi inputs will be diode drop plus 3.3 V (VCC of Pi). The current through the diode connected externally will be about 1.3 mA multiplied by 8 will give ~11 mA. Also, the input capacitance of all the Pi's inputs and 8 cables connected will make switching that current at high speed will get trouble with rise time and fall time too.

For your particular application, if you can buy one [74LVC245 buffer IC](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/sn74lvc245a.pdf), please go ahead with below solution.

You can simply connect the Arduino single output to all the 8 inputs and derive 3.3 V level signals from the outputs. the advantage is that it is simple to use (Breadboard friendly) and easy to connect to.

[image]

The input voltage can be up to 5.5 V. Hence, it can accept the Arduino's input and drive the Pi's input easily.

Comment: I will test and update with my results soon. Thanks!

Comment: just a quick question,I am confused between buying one of these since I am not really good at it. Can you recommend which one will be suited for my purpose amongst these? Thanks for the help. 
goo.gl/TJPthV , 
goo.gl/7I4Ew0, 
goo.gl/wTdNP1, 
goo.gl/w7cqOv, 
goo.gl/WE3R70

Comment: The first link I checked was alright. goo.gl/TJPthV but, wait a minutr3. If you do not have the IC AND have a NPN transistor AND have a requirement to drive only in one direction always. Then why not try the solution from Dmitry below. I suggest you to try it.

Comment: Sorry, the one I mentioned on the link isn't breadboard friendly. Let me search the one for you.

Comment: Is it alright to buy this one in SOT23 package?http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=SN74LVC2G17&&fileType=pdf advantage is that the chip has only 6 pins and for this application sufficient .

Answer (score 0):

While your ad-hoc solution with diodes might work, you might as well use a proper voltage level converter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcUIOK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

<sup>(ground connection between Arduino and all RPi boards is assumed)</sup>

Since you drive all 8 RPi boards with the same signal, you should convert the voltage level only once, then distribute that signal to all the RPi boards.

Answer (score 0):

The more classic diode level shift circuit is this one

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiL3hO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output of that can drive as many inputs as you like.